# Opcion SelectedItem Que vaya a otra pagina

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Tengo una lista que cuando seleccione un ítem me dirija a una pagina llamada Movimientoview intento referenciar Con el selectedItem pero no hace nada

Como hago la referencia a esa funcion Que viene de ViewModel

Este es mi codigo  :

```html
<ListView x:Name="Sustancias" ItemsSource="{Binding Sustancias}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding GoPageMovimiento}"
SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell IsEnabled="true">
        <Grid Padding="5,0,5,0">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Nombre}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
          <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="{Binding Cantidad,StringFormat='{0:n}' } " Font="Small" TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
            <Label Text="{Binding SiglaUnidad }" Font="Small" TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Sigla }" Font="Small" TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
          </StackLayout>
          <!--<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Source="ico_susbstance.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>-->
        </Grid>

      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Aqui Esta El ViewModel

```js
public ICommand MovimientoCommand => new Command(async (s) => await IrMovimiento());

 private async Task IrMovimiento()
        {
            try
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                await NavigationService.NavigateModalToAsync<MovimientoViewModel>();
                //await NavigationService.RemoveLastFromBackStackAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                await DialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("Error", e.Message, "Aceptar");
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

El utiliza un servicio de navegación Para que pase por el view.model El cual el evento itemselected no me sirve

Comment: Hola, pon por favor el título en **español**, a no ser que sea el código de error que te da. Si es el código de error, indícalo en la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que veo, lo que quieres es ir de una página lista a una página detalle seleccionando un item en la lista, para ello, primero reemplazamos `SelectedItem="{Binding GoPageMovimiento}"` por `ItemTapped="ItemTappedHandler"` en tu XAML de la siguiente manera:

```
<ListView x:Name="Sustancias" ItemsSource="{Binding Sustancias}" 
 ItemTapped="ItemTappedHandler"
SeparatorVisibility="Default" HasUnevenRows="True">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell IsEnabled="true">
        <Grid Padding="5,0,5,0">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Nombre}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"></Label>
          <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Text="{Binding Cantidad,StringFormat='{0:n}' } " Font="Small" TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
            <Label Text="{Binding SiglaUnidad }" Font="Small" TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
            <Label Text="{Binding Sigla }" Font="Small" TextColor="Gray" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
          </StackLayout>
          <!--<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Source="ico_susbstance.png" Aspect="AspectFill"/>-->
        </Grid>

      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Y en tu código .cs:

```
async void ItemTappedHandler(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e) {
        var item = (AquiVaTuModelo)e.Item;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ViewDetailPage(item));
}
```

Comment: OSea el cs que colocaste es el viewmodel o el del XAML que

Comment: el código del XAML.

Comment: item me da error

Comment: Bro necesito que esto pase por el viewModel

Comment: No hay mucha diferencia ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Es que necesito binding para utilizar el servicio de navegacion, Osea Que pase por viewmodel no por view

Comment: ¿Entiendes cómo funciona el patrón MVVM?

Comment: Haz Binding a un objeto del ViewModel. En el Set, comprueba lo que necesites y utiliza el servicio de navegación para ir donde necesites.